# UI::MainWindow cannot find member

Tags: c++, qt

I have created a .ui file that contains several UI Item Table Widgets named houseTable, carTable, and personTable. In my cpp file, I try to reference these widgets but I get the error `'class UI::MainWindow' has no member named 'houseTable'`. I am confused why this is happening when in my .ui file I have my object named 'houseTable'.

```
//mainwindow.cpp
ui->houseTable->setDescription("All houses:");
```

Comment: can you show the definition of houseTable from the ui file?

Comment: Are these members pointers? if they are not then you should be using `.` notation to access member functions like `ui.houseTable.setDescription("All houses");`

Comment: @HunterMcMillen sorry, what is a definition? where would i find this information?

Comment: @EdChum the TA provided us with the code `ui->houseTable->setDescription("All houses:");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include "ui_calculatorform.h"
class CalculatorForm : public QWidget
{
   ........................
   ...........................
private:
    Ui::CalculatorForm ui;
};

CalculatorForm::CalculatorForm(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
}
```

If I'm not wrong these steps should help.